# How to resolve The attribute 'Remove' in element <none> is unrecognized error in Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am updating the Xamarin.Forms package to 2.4 and adding CarouselView.xamarinforms package to my portable, Android and iOS projects and committed in to source tree. In another system, when I am pulling that branch and run the project it shows the following error. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same Xamarin versions on both machines?

Comment: your asking about xamarin.forms version?

Comment: I am using mac and desktop. In desktop visual studio xamarn version version is 4.5 and in mac visual studio xamarin.mac version is 3.4